# Why do review audits count towards the daily quota?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I've noticed that review audits take up from your limit of 20 reviews per day. Is there a specific reason that this is occurs?

I'd feel like the concept of a review audit, when passed, shouldn't necessarily take up from the 20-review quota. It's almost like a "Congratulations, you're paying attention! By *the way, because you're paying attention, that counts as part of your quota.*"

I have no idea what the Close Vote queue is like, but if there's audits there too, that could also impact the amount of practical work performed.

For example, in today's LQP queue, I got 2 audits, resulting in 18 actual LQP being handled, and 2 pats on the back for being fully awake, and there were still questions in the queue when I was done. I got credit for finishing 20, but in reality I checked only 18 questions for quality.

Comment: Same goes for the CVQ ... (except that we got 40 votes per daydue to the queue size being larger than 1000)...

Comment: There is an open feature request on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224209/review-audits-should-not-be-counted-to-the-count-of-daily-reviews

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Reiterating my comment from MSE: the assumption (or one of the assumptions?) behind these limits is that doing too much reviews can make you tired and less accurate. You exploit your capacity in exactly the same way during an audit as during an ordinary review, thus audit should count towards the daily quota.

Whether these limits are accurate, necessary etc. is irrelevant in the context of this particular issue, the point is that if we assume that quota is good, audits should count.

Comment: Not really. suggested edits, for example, are super-easy.

Comment: @JanDvorak Some of them are indeed. But I'm not getting what's your point (perhaps you've missed the last paragraph of my answer?).

Comment: Suggested edit audits don't exercise your endurance in any way. All they teach you is how to recognize crappy edits even faster.

Comment: @JanDvorak Audits exercise your endurance in the same way reviews do. They are based on real reviews and until it's over you don't know for sure whether it's an audit or not. Suggested edit audits sometimes are super-easy, because suggested edit reviews are sometimes super-easy.

Comment: The answer seems to make sense.

Comment: @BartoszKP Suggested edit audits are not based on real reviews.

Comment: @bjb568 Didn't know that, thanks. I think I understand now what Jan Dvorak meant. Still, even assuming they're easier on average, comparing them with other audits in terms of how exploiting they are, in terms of "ability to pay attention", "focus" etc. is a hazy psychological dispute, and thus, IMHO, pointless ;)

Comment: @JanDvorak My previous comment is also addressed to you :)

Comment: Suggested edit audits are usually obvious from miles away, nonsense title additions and nonsense closing remarks. I like to reject them because I like the (paraphrasing) "Good job, you're awesome" message. It's a shame that I have to press skip to not waste my review vote :-(